# php query does not retrieve any data?

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

well, i wanna pull out some data from a mysql view, but the wuery dos not seem to retrieve anything ( even though the view has data in it).

here is the code i've been "playing" with ( i'm using adodb for php)

```
$get_teachers=$db->Execute("select  * from lecturer ");

//$array=array();
//fill array with teacher for each lesson
for($j=0;$j<$get_teachers->fetchrow();++$j){
    /*$row2 = $get_lessons->fetchrow();
   $row3=$row2[0];
    $teach=array(array());
    //array_push($teach, $row3);
    $teach[$j]=mysql_fetch_array( $get_teachers, TYPE );
    //echo $row3;*/
    $row = $get_teachers->fetchrow();
    //$name=$row[0]+" "+$row[0]+"/n";
    //array_push($teach, $row1);
    echo $row[0]; echo " ";echo $row[1]." ";
    //$db->debug = true;

}
```

if i try something like "select name,surname from users", the query partially works . By partially i mean , while there are 2 users in the database, the loop only prints the last user.

the original query i wanted to execute was this

```
$get_teachers=$db->Execute("select  surname,name from users,assigned_to,lessons 
where users.UID=assigned_to.UID and lessons.LID=assigned_to.LID and
lessons.term='".$_GET['term']."'");
```

but because it didnt seem to do anything i tried with a view ( when you execute this in the phpmyadmin it works fine(by replacing the GET part with a number from 1 to 7 )

the tables in case you wonder are: users,assigned_to and lessons. ( assigned_to is a table connecting each user to a lesson he teaches by containing UID=userid and LID=lessonid ). What i wanted to do here is get the name+surname of the users who teach a lesson. Imagine a list tha displays each lesson+who teaches it based on the term that lesson is available.

Comment: Read the docs - examples on the first page! http://adodb.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thanks everybody :) i will surely look more into adodb documentation . thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at http://adodb.sourceforge.net/ I can see an example on the first page on how to use the library:

```
$rs = $DB->Execute("select * from table where key=123");
while ($array = $rs->FetchRow()) {
    print_r($array);
}
```

So, you should use:

```
while ($row = $get_teachers->fetchrow()) {
```

instead of:

```
for ($j = 0; $j < $get_teachers->fetchrow(); ++$j) {
```

The idea with `FetchRow()` is that it returns the next row in the sequence. It does not return the number of the last row, so you shouldn't use it as a condition in a `for` loop. You should call it every time you need the next row in the sequence, and, when there are no more rows, it will return `false`.

Also, take a look at the documentation for [`FetchRow()`](http://phplens.com/adodb/reference.functions.fetchrow.html).

Answer (score 0):

`for($j=0;$j<$get_teachers->fetchrow();++$j){`

... a few lines later ...

```
$row = $get_teachers->fetchrow();
```

See how you call `fetchrow()` twice before actually printing anything? You remove two rows from the result set for every 1 you actually use.

```
while ($row = $get_teachers->fetchrow()) {
```

instead and don't call `fetchrow()` again within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're fetching twice first in the loop

```
for($j=0;$j<$get_teachers->fetchrow();++$j){
    ... some code ...
    // And here you fetch again
    $row = $get_teachers->fetchrow();
```

You should use it like this

```
while ($row = $get_teachers->fetchrow()) {
```